# Want to know about Exclude Sitemap Option in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I have noticed Exclude Sitemap option is by default enabled as Yes. Does that mean it will not include that URL in the sitemap? If yes then how can I change that on all of my total URLs? Because that will put a negative impact on my site performance. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the site map from your side, steps are 

Steps to Remove Image URL from sitemap. xml in Magento 2:

1. Login to admin panel.
2. Navigate to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > XML Sitemap.
3. Expand Product Options.
4. Set “None” to Add Images into Sitemap.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just checked that it's already set to none, so it seems good. Do I need to tik on Use system value option?

Comment: yeah please try that also.